# Ignore returned expression in DQL

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have a DQL query containing a `SELECT` expression that's only used for ordering:

```sql
SELECT u, (u.orderTotal / u.orderCount) AS orderAverage
FROM User u
ORDER BY orderAverage
```

I have to use this trick because so far, [Doctrine does not support ordering by an expression](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/Fpkf7hwaIFY/2dLiyyj1ujUJ).

That works fine, expect that for a reason outside the scope of this question, I'd like to have only `u` returned by [getResult()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.AbstractQuery.html#_getResult):

```sql
[0] => object(User)
[1] => object(User)
```

and not a nested array containing `u` and `orderAverage`:

```sql
[0] =>
       [0] => object(User)
       ['orderAverage'] => float
[1] =>
       [0] => object(User)
       ['orderAverage'] => float
```

I thought I'd read somewhere that there was a DQL keyword for not returning an expression in the result, but I've failed to find it in the documentation. It'd be something like:

```sql
SELECT u, IGNORE (u.orderTotal / u.orderCount) AS orderAverage
FROM ...
```

Does that exist, or did I dream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to find it in the [EBNF documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#select-expressions).

The correct keyword is `HIDDEN`, and goes after `AS`:

```sql
SELECT u, (u.orderTotal / u.orderCount) AS HIDDEN orderAverage
```